# app.config “Could not find schema information” after converting to Visual Studio 2010 / .Net 4.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i am working on vb .net project. it was working fine till yesterday. i m trying to build it today but its giving me following build errors.

1 Could not find schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime'. 
2 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'version'.
3 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'.

i tried few things but it is not working fine. I tried selecting the DotNetConfig.xsd from the properties of app.config. it didnt work. I chose some other schema then it is selecting both the schemas. and throwing some other bunch of errors too. I tried killing the process from the task manager. i tried replacing the app.config.
What should i do?

P.S: i am using visual studio 2010 version.
and .net framework 4.0

Comment: post your app config

Comment: Try Rebuilding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Close the solution, then re-load it and Rebuild